TC eBPF: packets disappear after manipulating destination IP
I have written proxy in TC eBPF that changes the destination IP address based on some conditions. After manipulating the packet, the program fixes the IP checksum and returns TC_ACT_OK.
I attach the proxy to the ingress path but it seems like the kernel does not like the modified packets and drops them because the packets never leave through egress.
Below I have a simplified version of my ebpf function but I experience the same problem when attaching it. (This one statically sets 10.0.0.2 as the destination IP.)
Any ideas what the issue is? How can I investigate why the kernel drops the packets?
Thank you 
SEC("tc")
int handle_ingress(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)skb->data_end;

    struct ethhdr *eth = data;
    if ((void *)eth + sizeof(*eth) > data_end)
        return TC_ACT_SHOT; 

    if (eth->h_proto != bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP))
        return TC_ACT_OK; 

    struct iphdr *ip = data + sizeof(*eth);
    if ((void *)ip + sizeof(*ip) > data_end)
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;

    __be32 new_dst = bpf_htonl(0x0A000002);  // 10.0.0.2 in network byte order

    // Recalculate the IP checksum
    __s64 sum = bpf_csum_diff((void *)&ip->daddr, 4, (void *)&new_dst, 4, 0);
    if (bpf_skb_store_bytes(skb, sizeof(struct ethhdr) + offsetof(struct iphdr, daddr), (void *)&new_dst, 4, 0) < 0)
        return TC_ACT_SHOT; // Drop packet if modification fails
    bpf_l3_csum_replace(skb, sizeof(struct ethhdr) + offsetof(struct iphdr, check), 0, sum, 0);

    return TC_ACT_OK;
}

I would expect the packet to leave through the egress path because there is an interface on the same network that has the IP 10.0.0.2. It is connected via a virtual bridge (I use virtual Linux namespaces).

I would check with pwru where the packets are dropped.
